# How to display multiple selection of user by toString() and setter and getter ? in Java

Tags: java

How can i retrieve 2 data that user select in java class through the setter and getter ? 
Work in a assignment of java language now and when i create a toString() inside another java class(to display in the main class),i use [this.flowername] to display the flower that user enter but it only show the 2nd flower(first flower has been replaced).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the result that you're currently seeing as well as the result you expect to see

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not aware of the exact code that you are trying to implement, I'll suggest a generic approach.

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

- You should use an array of strings in the first class to store all the values of flowers being entered and then call the object in the second class and access the array as **this.arr**.
- Another way to achieve is that you create separate objects for each flower in the second class, perform set for each respective object and then in the toString() method, append data from each object via the getter of the object.